# How to avoid clash between the function same parameter name

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following codes:

```
Function test1(Optional pObj As Object = Nothing)
 If pObj Is Nothing Then
  Set pObj = ActiveWorkbook
 End If
 Call test2(pObj)
 Set pObj = Nothing
End Function

Function test2(Optional pObj As Object = Nothing)
 If pObj Is Nothing Then
  Set pObj = ActiveWorkbook
 End If
 Set pObj = Nothing
End Function

Sub test()
 Call test1
End Sub
```

Right after ‘test2’ set the pObj to Nothing, pObj of ‘test1’ also becomes Nothing. At first I thought that since they are in different function, they will not clash into each other. Is there a way that after ‘test2’ set the pObj to Nothing, it will not affect the pObj in ‘test1’?

I can try to rename the pObj in test1 and test2 into different name but I just want to know if there is a way to differentiate each within the function.

Comment: It shouldn't affect the `pObj` once it is passed into the function. Are you sure the `pObj` in `test1` becomes `Nothing` after calling `test2`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I tried to Watch the pObj for both functions when I noticed that there is something wrong when I go back to test1 and that’s when I found out that it becomes Nothing after test2.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference if you use them as a parameter. So pObj in test2 and pObj in test1 reference the same instance of an object. Try to pass them by value. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/byval

Comment: `Function test2(Optional ByVal pObj As Object = Nothing)` should fix it

Comment: ByVal works. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, just to be clear: it is not related to the fact that the variable names are the same.

Comment: @Tenior
in vba everything is passed byref when not explicit declared ByVal.
This is the default in VBA while in VB.Net ByVal is default for ValueParameter.
This makes it so critical when moving von vba to vb.net.

Comment: I have explained about `ByRef` and `ByVal` [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naKfjXbFfJA). Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Rory. Thank you for the info. I understand much better now because of your comment. Awhile ago, I thought that changing the name would solve it but it was not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are normally used to return values/objects. Since you're not returning anything with the functions, you might as well go with a normal Sub.

To not have it affect the variable, you can specify to see it ByVal since it defaults to ByRef otherwise. However, while it does work here as ByVal, there are caveats to it: [see more here](https://wellsr.com/vba/2019/excel/vba-byval-vs-byref/)

```
Sub test1(Optional pObj As Object = Nothing)
    If pObj Is Nothing Then
        Set pObj = ActiveWorkbook
    End If
    Call test2(pObj)
    If pObj Is Nothing Then 'you won't get in here with the ByVal in test2
        Debug.Print "test2 made it Nothing"
    End If
    Set pObj = Nothing
End Sub

Sub test2(Optional ByVal pObj As Object = Nothing)
    If pObj Is Nothing Then
        Set pObj = ActiveWorkbook
    End If
    Set pObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Or have test2 pass the Object to a new variable which won't change pObj after changing pObj2 either:

```
Sub test2(Optional pObj As Object = Nothing)
    Dim pObj2 As Object
    Set pObj2 = pObj
    If pObj2 Is Nothing Then
        Set pObj2 = ActiveWorkbook
    End If
    Set pObj2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I’m returning values on my functions. I just didn’t include more code in order to limit the code when I’m testing it. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome and happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

### Passing Objects

- Here is a scenario that applies to the *Workbook* object. It might be different than the one you had in mind. Hopefully, it will further help you fully understand passing objects to procedures (functions).
- Only `Test1` is called by the main procedure (doesn't 'know' about `Test2`), while `Test2` is only (optionally) called by the `Test1` procedure.

**The Main (Calling) Procedure**

```vb
Sub TestTheFunctions()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    ' Test when 'wb Is Nothing' (workbook not set)
    MsgBox "Result: " & Test1(wb), vbInformation, "Test No.1" ' or just 'Test1'
    
    ' Test when 'Not wb Is Nothing' (workbook set)
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    MsgBox "Result: " & Test1(wb), vbInformation, "Test No.2"
    
End Sub
```

**The Functions**

```vb
Function Test1(Optional ByVal wb As Workbook = Nothing) As String
    If wb Is Nothing Then ' use the active workbook
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            Test1 = "Nope"
            MsgBox "No visible workbooks open!", vbExclamation
            Exit Function
        End If
        ' do something with 'wb'...
        
        ' ... and return a result, e.g.:
        Test1 = wb.Name
    Else ' use the passed workbook
        Test1 = Test2(wb)
    End If
End Function

' This will only run if a workbook was passed so no need for 'Optional'.
Function Test2(ByVal wb As Workbook) As String
    ' do something (different?) with 'wb' ...
    
    ' ... and return a result, e.g.:
    Test2 = wb.Name
End Function
```